# Speed Up Finding Occurrences in Multiple Sheets via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find-occurrences

with the below code I m finding how many times a contact has been reached. In order to do so, the formula is using a named range (Weeks) and search for the partner name across multiple sheets.

I am not using a simple formula because the file change depending on the person that is using the file so I am using VBA.

Although the below code works, this is a very slow and I am wondering if someone could help me in speeding it up or could suggest me other methods to get the same results.

```
Sub ContactCycle()

Dim WsMaster As Worksheet
Dim WsLastRow As Long
Dim MyContactCycleRange As Range, cell As Range

Set WsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
WsLastRow = WsMaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set MyContactCycleRange = WsMaster.Range("AB5:AB" & WsLastRow)
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each cell In MyContactCycleRange
cell.Formula = "=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Weeks&""'!""&""$A$6:$A$45""),$B5))>0,1,0)"
Next cell
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it faster with outputrange as per below:

```
Sub ContactCycle()
Dim WsMaster As Worksheet
Dim WsLastRow As Long
Dim OutputRange As Range
Dim tmpCalc As XlCalculation: tmpCalc = Application.Calculation 'Save setting
Const OutputColumn As Long = 28 ' "AB"

Set WsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Set MyContactCycleRange = WsMaster.Range("AB5:AB" & WsLastRow)
Set OutputRange = WsMaster.Range(WsMaster.Cells(5, OutputColumn), WsMaster.Cells(WsLastRow, OutputColumn))


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Makes things slightly faster
     With OutputRange
        .Formula = "=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Weeks&""'!""&""$A$6:$A$45""),$B5))>0,1,0)"  'This will fill down automatically
        .Calculate 'Needed because Calculation is currently manual
        .Value = .Value 'Convert the formulae into flat values
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .NumberFormat = "0"
    End With
        Application.Calculation = tmpCalc 'Restore setting saved earlier
End Sub
```